# Feature based permissions for roles in asp.net mvc angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

We need to develop an application using Asp.Net MVC 6, Entitty Framework 7 and angularjs Frameworks.

Our Application will have 5 major roles:

- Super Admin
- Admin
- Sales Manager
- Sales Executive
- Customer

Customer itself can create its users and give particular access rights to its users ex: Driver, Accountant etc. in our system

For the above mentioned 5 major roles we just need to give access to pages, so that we can easily handle, but the problem is with users of customer. As users of customers will have page level as well as feature level access for a particular page.

We need a solution for this type of scenario with the above mentioned frameworks.

Comment: Can you share some code and explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have not started the code so far, I am looking for some concrete solutions, out of which I go with the best one.